# Error after Upgrading FOS UserBundle from 1.2 to 2.0 in Symfony 2.1

Tags: propel, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.1

I have a project in Symfony 2.1, with PropelBundle, and FOS UserBundle. I upgraded FOS UserBundle with Composer from 1.2 to the latest version (2.0) and followed the instruction to delete the "propel_user_class" definition in the app/config/config.yml file as indicated in the [Upgrade.md file](http://symfony.vivons-ici.fr/vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Upgrade.md). My new config is as follows:

```
# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyVendor\MyBundle\Model\Member
    registration:
        form:
            type: myvendor_user_registration
```

After doing so and rebuilding the model, I get the following error when submitting the user login form: **"The user provider must return a UserInterface object."**

I think there is an issue with the FOS UserBundle not recognizing my user class "Member" and its properties. In FOS/UserBundle's earlier version (1.2) the [FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface was implemented by a proxy object](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/index.md), thus my previous config (which was working) included the following:

```
user_class: MyVendor\MyBundle\FOSUserBundle\Propel\UserProxy
propel_user_class: MyVendor\MyBundle\Model\Member
```

My UserProxy.php file used to extend FOS\UserBundle\Propel\UserProxy and add the properties that were specific to my project. Is that UserProxy.php no longer needed with the new UserBundle version?
What else do I have to do to make the new UserBundle version work?
The above mentioned Upgrade.md file also talks about the profile form no longer wrapping the user in a CheckPassword class, and the generation of the token not being done by the User class anymore. However, I'm not sure whether I have to do any changes because of that? Could anyone give me some guidelines?

I tried to move my Member, Circle, and MemberCircle classes definition Schema to app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/config/propel/schema.xml to override the schema inside FOS User Bundle as indicated in the documentation, while telling the classes in my own bundle to extend the ones in FOS UserBundle but I get the following error when trying to build the propel model with "app/console propel:build":

> [RuntimeException]
>   "MyProjectName/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/config/propel/schema.xml"
>   resource is hidden by a resource from the "MyBundle"
>   derived bundle. Create a
>   "MyProjectName/app/Resources/MyBundle/config/propel/schema.xml"
>   file to override the bundle resource.

I kept the namespace "FOS\UserBundle\Propel" in the app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/config/propel/schema.xml file. How can I make that schema override the one in FOS/UserBundle? Can I use classes named "Member" (for User) and "Circle" (for Group) in it?