# Symfony cannot find template on prod server

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Should be simple enough. Everything works in my local environment, but not on my prod server (neither prod nor dev environment). I get an error that the FOS template cannot be found:

```
Unable to find template "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig".
```

My code is simple:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
```

I'm going from my local Windows machine to a Linux box. I've read case sensitivity might be the culprit, but it doesn't seem like it.

The FOS bundle is in the normal place: `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle`.

I'm having trouble diagnosing - any ideas? Did things get screwed up when I FTPd? Permissions issues? What are the common gotchas? I'm desparate!

Update: A clue. I ran `assetic:dump` and got

```
[RuntimeException]
".../app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig" resource is hidden by a 
resource from the "*******Bundle" derived bundle. Create a
".../app/Resources/*******Bundle/views/layout.html.twig" file to override the bundle 
resource.
```

[This question seems relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837636/error-after-upgrading-fos-userbundle-from-1-2-to-2-0-in-symfony-2-1)

Another update: I was using `getParent()` in my own bundle to override the templates. I switched to [the first method in the docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) but now the templates in `app/resources` simply aren't having an effect. It's going straight to the default form template with a white background.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run the production environment on your Windows machine?

Comment: Yes. I'm afraid they're out of sync somehow, with git stuff, cache stuff, who knows. I've checked all that, but still having a hard time.

Comment: Or it's a Linux thing, with route names (@ syntax), or upper/lower case, etc.

Comment: Or permissions...what are common permissions gotchas?

Comment: If its a stock standard FOSUserBundle install and all you're trying to do is extend its layout, then I doubt there would be an issue with case. Are you using `ApcClassLoader` in `app.php`?

Comment: It's not enabled, no.

Comment: Please try loading the same page in using app_dev.php and try loading in production

Comment: @Sethunath I get the error in both environments.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: @juanreyesv I've done it manually (deleting the folder). When I run that command I get 'Class simplearray does not exist'.

Comment: Did you composer install correctly?

Comment: I think, how can I tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a upper/lower case/namespacing thing. I thought my local files were in sync with remotes but they were not.

Just check your whole directory & all namespaces in the FOS bundle!

Comment: You are worth gold. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Had "Views" instead of "views"... Worked in locale environment, but not on my server. Thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem and "solved" it by renaming my `layout.html.twig` inside my bundle's Resources/views folder to bundle-layout.html.twig and adapting my templates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the `resource is hidden by a resource` error by moving the template in the good bundle extension.

Specifically from `app/Resources/FOSUSerBundle/views/ChangePassword`
to `src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/views/ChangePassword`

I confounded FOSUser & SonataUser.